# How to get values from JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I get values from JSON objects with javascript. I am able to get keys [(see fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/3woafcz7/)  but I cannot get the values corresponding to the keys

My code is below

```
var getKeys = function (arr) {
        var key, keys = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (key in arr[i]) {
                if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        alert(keys);
    };

var a = [ { name: "Carrot", category: "Vegetable", healthiness: "Adequate" }, 
  { name: "Pork Shoulder", category: "Meat", healthiness: "Questionable" }, 
  { name: "Bubblegum", category: "Candy", healthiness: "Super High"} ]
getKeys(a);
```

What I want to console.log is {key:value}

Comment: a is not a valid JSON object see http://json.org/example.html

Comment: Are you just wanting the values without the keys?  Why not just push(arr[i][key])

Comment: @avrono you're right, but OP only have the mistake in the nomenclature, he has got an array of objects, not a JSON, but the issue is not that.

Comment: @marcos, corect - but cannot give a general answer without this distinction

Answer (score 2):

Simply.

https://jsfiddle.net/3woafcz7/1/

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  for (key in arr[i]) {
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(arr[i][key]); //that's the new
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer what I would like to have is to have each key with its values

Comment: What format do you need? A text output? For example `key: value`?

Comment: yes simply being able to get each key with its value separatly

Comment: With the code in this answer, you get two variables `keys` and `values`, that contains an array each one. So `key[2]` have a key and its value you can find in `values[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

`key` only show the properties name, use this `arr[i][key]` like following to get the value :

```
keys.push(arr[i][key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want?
You want to alert the key plus it's value?

```
var getKeys = function (arr) {
    var key, keys = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (key in arr[i]) {
            if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key +": "+ arr[i][key]);
            }
        }
    }
    alert(keys);
};
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

just use map function

```js
var a = [ 
 { name: "Carrot", category: "Vegetable", healthiness: "Adequate" }, 
 { name: "Pork Shoulder", category: "Meat", healthiness: "Questionable" }, 
 { name: "Bubblegum", category: "Candy", healthiness: "Super High"} 
]

var names = a.map(function(obj){
 return obj.name;
})
var categorys = a.map(function(obj){
 return obj.category;
})

document.write('name===>'+names)
document.write('<br>categorys==>'+categorys)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an array containing multiple objects created from the key/value pairs of the objects in `a`, this should do the trick:

```
function getPairs(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
    for (var prop in c) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[prop] = c[prop];
      p.push(obj);
    }
    return p;
  }, []);
}

getPairs(a);
```

OUTPUT

```
[{"name":"Carrot"},{"category":"Vegetable"},{"healthiness":"Adequate"},{"name":"Pork Shoulder"},{"category":"Meat"},{"healthiness":"Questionable"},{"name":"Bubblegum"},{"category":"Candy"},{"healthiness":"Super High"}];
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3woafcz7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

to get keys of an object you can use : 
    Object.keys(a);

---

```
var a = [ { name: "Carrot", category: "Vegetable", healthiness: "Adequate" }, 
  { name: "Pork Shoulder", category: "Meat", healthiness: "Questionable" }, 
  { name: "Bubblegum", category: "Candy", healthiness: "Super High"} ]

var b = { name: "SSSS", category: "VVVVV", healthiness: "AAAAA" };
```

---

```
// using generator (ES6 only)
Object.prototype.iter_values = function*(){
    var keys = Object.keys(this);
    for (var k=0;k < keys.length; k++) {
        yield this[keys[k]];
    };
};
function test_iter(o){
    for (v of o.iter_values()){ // note the 'of' keyword
        console.log(v);
    }
};
```

---

```
// using array (ES5)
Object.prototype.values = function() {
    var keys = Object.keys(this);
    var values = [];
    for (var k=0;k < keys.length; k++) {
        values.push(this[keys[k]]);
    };
    return values;
};  

function test_array(o){
    console.log(o.values());
};
```

---

if you want to loop on values, use generator, else array will be less verbose.